# How to return 'null' instead of 'undefined' from select element

Tags: jquery

How can I return null instead of a 'undefined' from a select element.

Basically I have 4 selects at the moment, but only the first one is populated with data at this point, but I want to grab the value from all of them when working with them.

```
<select class="changeValue" id="drpOne"></select>
<option id=1>1</option>
<option id=2>2</option>
<option id=3>3</option>

<select class="changeValue" id="drpTwo"></select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.changeValue').change(function() {
    var data = {};
    data["Id1"] = $('#drpOne:selected').attr("id");
    data["Id2"] = $('#drpTwo:selected').attr("id");
```

In this case, drpTwo will return 'undefined'. Is there anyway to get a null instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `or` operator `||`:

```
data["Id2"] = $('#drpTwo:selected').attr("id") || null;
```

Comment: Just curious, won't this assign the truth value instead? Thanks

Comment: Nope, Javascript is strange but cool in this way. `x = null || 3; x == 3`, `x = 2 || 3; x == 2`

Comment: No, in JS it'll return the result of first statement if it's not null/undefined (I don't remember exactly right now) or the value of the second one.

Comment: it returns the first truthy component, or the last one if none are truthy.